# Webform Address Element and Canada provinces

Tags: 8, webforms

In the webform (drupal 8) module I am using the address element and notice that the state/province field does not contain any Canadian provinces - only US States and Territories.

Where can I add the Canadian Provinces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the default state options via /admin/structure/webform/config/options/manage.

I recommend installing the [Address module](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) for substantially better international address support.